# Редирект, вместо эсепшена в behaviors Yii2+RBAC

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте!

Использую `behaviors` вместе с RBAC для ограничения доступа к определенной части сайта(несколько контроллеров). Проблема в том, что если у пользователя не подходящая роль генерируется исключение Forbidden.

Хотелось бы, чтобы вместо этого был редирект на определенной страницу. Возможно ли сделать это прямо в настройках `behaviors`?

Пока использую данное решение, но не уверен насколько оно правильно:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if(!Yii::$app->user->can("ruleName")){
        $this->redirect(["controller/action"]);
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: Вполне приемлемое решение. Можно принять, что поведение обеспечивает базовые возможности. Далее вы уже сверху добавляете свою логику. Я в своих проектах так же делаю проверку на наличие роли перед тем как выводить ссылки, пункты меню, вкладки и кнопки. В случае, если у пользователя недостаточно прав для перехода, просто не показываю элемент управления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У фильтра `AccessControl` можно задать функцию `denyCallback`, которая будет вызываться, когда доступ для пользователя запрещен.

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    // ...
                ],
                'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                    // тут пишете, что вам надо (редирект)
                }
            ],

        ];
    }
```

[ссылка на исходник](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/AccessControl.php)